# Javafx: Tableview of ManyToMany relationship

Tags: list, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I'm trying to create a tableview which shows each activity, and the members who are participating. Activity has a list of members and a member has a list of activities. I'm stuck at getting the columns to show the activity name, and a member of that activity. I'd like to show an activity-member combination on each row. I'm also not sure how I'm supposed to populate the table, since I'm passing a list of activities.

This is what I'm trying to go for.

```
+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| Activity |    Type    | Member name | Member surname | Member rank |
+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| act1     | Internship | Peter       | Peterson       |           1 |
| act1     | Internship | Bob         | Bobber         |           3 |
| act2     | Sport      | Tim         | Tom            |           1 |
| act2     | Sport      | Bob         | Bobber         |           3 |
+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

```java
    public class ActivityListController extends GridPane {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Activity> tblActivities;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Activity, String> colActivityName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Activity, String> colType;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Activity, List<String>> colFirstName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Activity, String> colLastName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Activity, String> colRank;
    private final DomeinController dc;

    public ActivityListController(DomainController dc) {
        this.dc = dc;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().
                getResource("ActivityList.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        colActivity.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
        colActivy.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getMembers().???));
        colLastName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getMembers().???));
        colRank.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getMembers().???));

        tblActivities.setItems(dc.getAllActivities());
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you rethink your data model. Does it make sense for an `Activity` to have a list of `Member` and for `Member` to have a list of `Activity` which also has a list of `Member` and so on ...?

Comment: It's supposed to represent a ManyToMany model, where an activity has a list of members who will partake, and each member has a list of activities which he/she partakes in